# PHP: scandir() is too slow

Tags: php, scandir

I have to make a function that lists all subfolders into a folder. I have a no-file filter, but the function uses scandir() for listing. That makes the application very slow. Is there an alternative of scandir(), even a not native php function?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just how many files/dirs are in the directory you're scanning? It shouldn't be THAT slow, unless you're doing a `stat()` on each dir as it comes up, or there's thousands of files in there.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#96326

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#73062

Comment: have a look at the php manual under "Example #2 PHP 4 alternatives to scandir()"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use readdir which may be faster, something like this:

```
function readDirectory($Directory,$Recursive = true)
{
    if(is_dir($Directory) === false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        $Resource = opendir($Directory);
        $Found = array();

        while(false !== ($Item = readdir($Resource)))
        {
            if($Item == "." || $Item == "..")
            {
                continue;
            }

            if($Recursive === true && is_dir($Item))
            {
                $Found[] = readDirectory($Directory . $Item);
            }else
            {
                $Found[] = $Directory . $Item;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $Found;
}
```

May require some tweeking but this is essentially what scandir does, and it should be faster, if not please write an update as i would like to see if i can make a faster solution.

Another issue is if your reading a very large directory your filling an array up within the internal memory and that may be where your memory is going.

You could try and create a function that reads in offsets so that you can return 50 files at a time!

reading chunks of files at a time would be just as simple to use, would be like so:

```
$offset = 0;
while(false !== ($Batch = ReadFilesByOffset("/tmp",$offset)))
{
    //Use $batch here which contains 50 or less files!

    //Increment the offset:
    $offset += 50;
}
```

Comment: everything seems perfect, but how to disable this . and .. folders. I also have an empty index, that i dont want to list. I guess it's in the catch(Exception), but how to format it?

Comment: Ive updated so that it does not contain `.` or `..` but im not sure what you mean in regards to the empty index

Answer (score 5):

Don't write your own. PHP has a Recursive Directory Iterator built specifically for this:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

As a rule of thumb (aka not 100% of the time), since it's implemented in straight C, anything you build in PHP is going to be slower.

Comment: Unless you are writing a real time software the "slowness" of php doesn't matter at all

Comment: Wrap the directory iterator in a `ParentIterator` (or a bespoke iterator filter) and bam, no files.

Comment: The slowness matters in many circumstances.