# PHP most efficient way to list the files in a very large directory

Tags: php, scandir

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Get the Files inside a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086105/get-the-files-inside-a-directory)
>   [PHP: scandir() is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172784/php-scandir-is-too-slow)

I have a directory with tens of thousands of files in it and I want to display a list of these files on a page.  I tried doing it with scandir and it takes forever.  What would be an efficient method of achieving this?

Comment: Which of these have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=list+files+directory+php

Comment: You will also want to read [Putting Glob to Test](http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/28/putting-glob-to-the-test/)

Comment: i've tried those methods - they work fine with a thousand or so files but it takes an age to return hundreds of thousands of files into an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172784/php-scandir-is-too-slow

Comment: @John if you really already tried scandir, opendir, glob and iterators then please update your question to state that. maybe even add some code and performance numbers. there is no point in having us repeat all the methods that can easily be found in the dozens other questions asking the same.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to have hundreds of thousands of files in a directory on any operating platform that I know... common practise is always to split them across subdirectories

Answer (score 9):

I recommend using [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) or [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

Comment: I recommend `FilesystemIterator` over `DirectoryIterator`.

Comment: @salathe +1 See also question [Difference between `DirectoryIterator` and `FileSystemIterator`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532064/difference-between-directoryiterator-and-filesystemiterator). Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't benchmarked them, but your other options are

glob() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

opendir() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

Comment: which one of these two(glob or opendir) performs better?

Comment: opendir is faster: https://www.phparch.com/2010/04/putting-glob-to-the-test/

Answer (score 1):

```
$directory=opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/directory/');
  while ($file = readdir($directory)) {
    if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
      echo $file."<br>";
    }
  }
closedir($directory);
```

Comment: The whole point is that this method is too slow

Comment: @ValRedchenko I wouldn't be so sure on that statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692764/readdir-vs-scandir