# Read all files in a directory and return a list in php

Tags: php, scandir

With scandir i can get the files but they are ugly displayed:

```
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => jan-spaceship.jpg [3] => jan-tychostation.jpg [4] => johan-mars.jpg [5] => mary-132786.jpg [6] => mary-mars.jpg )
```

What i want is a custom div with the name and maybe even display the image (it are all images). Is that possible with a foreach loop or a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found already an anser:

```
        $fileList = glob('uploads/*');

    //Loop through the array that glob returned.
    foreach($fileList as $filename){
       //Simply print them out onto the screen.
       echo $filename, '<br>'; 
    }
```

Comment: Where are you displaying the image in this?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, opendir and readdir seem to be more efficient in case of large content folders since they iterate one by one instead of loading all file names at once.

Comment: @vivek_23 that was an option, it don't need it. But when i do implement it, i will share it!

Comment: @vivek_23 do you have a link or something where i can check it out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692764/readdir-vs-scandir#:~:text=1%5D%20readdir%20returns%20the%20name,all%20the%20entries%20are%20read.

Comment: You will see more performance differences when a folder has thousands of images. Readdir is more production mode suitable unless a folder has very few images which can be done with scandir

Comment: @vivek_23 Yeah but it is only for a school assignment. So i am happy if it works. If i am gonna use it in real life i will watch a lot of tutorials but for now it isn't worth my time to check wich is better.

Comment: Fair enough. Stackoverflow is a place where we usually bring out the best solution possible so that others can benefit from it.